# Convert -51 to a signed magnitude binary number using the smallest of bits to represent it

Tags: architecture, binary, twos-complement

I got this question from a textbook, I'm not sure I am understanding the "using the smallest number of bits" part.

51 in binary is `0011 0011`

I thought to get -51, we convert to two's compliment.

```
    0011 0011
   -flip bits-
    1100 1100
   - add one -
    ---------
    1100 1101
```

So `1100 1101` is -51 in two's compliment. But how do we represent that in signed magnitude with the smallest number of bits? Confused by that part.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking `0011` `0011` you should be using `0110011` as you need only 6 digits to make 51, and take one extra bit for the sign.